# Kotlin/Native compileKotlinIosX64 task fails when building iOS app

Tags: kotlin, multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project. I recently updated to Kotlin 1.4-M2 (I need it to solve some issues with Ktor).
After updating all the required libraries, resolving all gradle issues and having my Android project compile successfully, I now encounter the following error when building the iOS app:

```
Task :shared:compileKotlinIosX64
e: Compilation failed: Could not find declaration for unbound symbol org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrSimpleFunctionPublicSymbolImpl@56f11f08
* Source files: [all shared folder kt files]
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.4-M2 / Kotlin: 1.4.0
 * Output kind: LIBRARY
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find declaration for unbound symbol org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrSimpleFunctionPublicSymbolImpl@56f11f08
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ExternalDependenciesGeneratorKt.getDeclaration(ExternalDependenciesGenerator.kt:76)
```

The curious thing is that in Source files it shows all the files in the shared code folder. I checked and absolutely all kt files appear in there. So my guess is that it is some issue when building the shared code, but does not seem specific of any library.

This is a slightly reduced version of how my **build.gradle.kts** looks like:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("io.fabric")
}

// CocoaPods requires the podspec to have a version.
version = "1.0"

tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    ios()
    android()

cocoapods {
    // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
    summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
    homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
}

sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serializationVersion")
                api("org.kodein.di:kodein-di:7.1.0-kotlin-1.4-M3-84")
                implementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.2")

                api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")

                api("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:$multiplatformSettingsVersion")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
}
}
```

And the library versions are as follows:

```
val ktorVersion = "1.3.2-1.4-M2"
val kotlinVersion = "1.4-M2"
val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.7-native-mt-1.4-M2"
val serializationVersion = "0.20.0-1.4-M2"
val multiplatformSettingsVersion = "0.6-1.4-M2"
```

It's worth mentioning this was building correctly in iOS when using 1.3.72.

Comment: First question, how did Mockk work? There's no native implementation.

Comment: @KevinGalligan Good question! It didn't. I did this app for Android first and used it there, without knowing that little detail. Now I can't use it anymore sadly. I will remove it shortly...

Comment: Also, unless libraries aren't available, I'd move to then RC version instead of M2

Comment: @KevinGalligan yes, I was holding onto that because of coroutines but actually I just checked and they just released it yesterday. Will give that a try

Comment: @KevinGalligan Thanks for your suggestion, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KevinGalligan suggested, I updated Kotlin and all related libs to 1.4.0-rc and the problem was solved.

The root issue with 1.4-M2 remains unknown.